ERROR: CreateProcessCommon:559: execvpe(/bin/bash) failed: No such file or directory
Whenever I run bash on a Windows terminal, I get hit with this.

ERROR: CreateProcessCommon:559: execvpe(/bin/bash) failed: No such file or directory

I've installed WSL and enabled dev mode.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

For anyone who stumbled across this error on Windows:

wsl --list to find available distros.
wsl --setdefault DISTRO-NAME to set default distro.

I set it to Ubuntu & it fixed Bash on Terminal.
Ref:

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9018
https://pureinfotech.com/set-default-distro-wsl2-windows-10/


Please have a look at Can I answer my own question? and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: Accept Your Own Answers.

Thank you. Was exactly my problem - Docker Desktop was taking over OpenSUSE in my case.
